# JQuery, ASCX and webmethods not seems to be working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have a cascading dropdown (3 of them) Type, Categories and Sub Categories. Type loads first and upon selection of Type, Category load and selection of Category, Sub Category loads.
Also i have 2 buttons, "Add Category" and "Add Sub Category" Upon clicking on these buttons, i call a JQuery Modal Form to add them. I use Webmethod in code behind to add them to database

This works perfectly in ASPX page.

Since I need use this in 3-4 pages, i thought of making the above as User control  (ASCX). When i try to use this in a webpage, the webmethods in ASCX don't get called.

Is my approach correct? what should be done for my scenario

lOoking forward for your suggestions.

Thanks in advance
Karthik

Answer (score 6):

i dont think you can have a WebMethod within a ASCX Control.
I solved it for my Problem like this:

AJAXBridge:

```
namespace Demo{
public partial class AjaxBridge : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static string Control_GetTest()
    {
        return Control.GetTest();
    }
}}
```

Control.ascx.cs

```
namespace Demo{
public partial class Control : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    HttpContext.Current.Session["test"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    // ALMOST A WEB METHOD
    public static string GetTest()
    {
        return " is " + HttpContext.Current.Session["test"];
    }
}}
```

Control.ascx

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
var dataSend = {};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "AjaxBridge.aspx/Control_GetTest",
    data: dataSend,
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function(data) {
        alert("before");
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Page Load Time from Session " + data.d);
    },
    fail: function() {
        alert("fail");
    }
});    </script>
```

So you have one ASPX which acts basically like a Interface for all AJAX Methods in all your Web Controls. There also some advantages like having overview and control of all exposed WebMethods, which makes it a lot easier to handle security matters (eg. with Annotations).

Answer (score 0):

Was your web method was a static method in the code behind that was marked with WebMethod attribute as described in the "Calling Static Methods in an ASP.NET Web Page" section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998(VS.90).aspx) before you moved it?  If so this type of webmethod only works at the page level and cannot be used in a usercontrol.  For an alternative read the first two sections of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998(VS.90).aspx).

Comment: Yes the web methods are static. The same works if i have it as norml aSPX pages and not as web user controls. 

BTW i am using ASP.NET 2.0 with JQuery

Comment: @KarthikK, Then I stand by my answer that you can't move them into a user control and have them work.